# where do I find an image of 15.10 to install on my desktop.

Tags: 15.10, downloads

until I get 15.10 on the machine, I cannot perform a network upgrade to 16.10.  The DVD with 16.10 on it fails on the reboot to to use the S/W

Comment: How do you know 16.04, 14.04 or 12.04 won't work? How do you know 15.10 will?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the ISO image from the ['old releases'](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/wily) website, where Ubuntu 15.10 is archived.
But I think you'd better perform a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.10 - because in this special case upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.10 would mean :

- first upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- and then upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 !